# Unity сохраняет не все данные

Tags: unity3d

Делаю кликер и столкнулся с такой проблемой. При Сохранении данных через PlayerPrefs сохраняется только score а остальное нет.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.
Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class But : MonoBehaviour{
    public int score;
    public int scoreAdd;
    public float lvFloat;
    public float lvAdd;
    public int lv;
    public int priceLv = 150;
    public Text clickText;
    public Text sliderText;
    public Text LvPrice;
    public Slider slider;
    public Button butLv;
    public Animator butLvAni;
    public GameObject effect;
    void Start(){
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Score")){
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ScoreAdd", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("lvFloat", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lv", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("lvAdd", 0.01f);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("priceLv", priceLv);
        }
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
        scoreAdd = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ScoreAdd");
        lvFloat = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("lvFloat");
        lv = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lv");
        lvAdd = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("lvAdd");
        priceLv = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("priceLv");
    }
    void Update(){
        if(lvFloat >= 1){
            butLv.interactable = true;
            butLvAni.SetBool("lvUp", true);
            LvPrice.text = priceLv.ToString() + "$";
        }
        clickText.text = score.ToString() + "$";
        slider.value = lvFloat;
        sliderText.text = lv.ToString() + "lv";
        
    }
    public void Click(){
        Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        score+=scoreAdd;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);
        if( lvFloat < 1 ){
            lvFloat += lvAdd;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lvFloat", score);
        }
    } 
 
}
```

Comment: Сами дебажить пробовали? В методе OnClick чему равно значение lvFloat?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @АлександрДаниловский и советую установить `Debug.Log("Score value setted as:  " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");)` после `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);` какой нибудь, и посмотреть задаётся ли это значение, и также с  `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lvFloat", score);` ответ где то тут. Может где то удаляется Score значение из Prefs и при старте его никогда не бывает? Потому что именно при старте вы проверяете Score из Prefs, обратите внимание